# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: text.DefaultSource

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have a scala maven application with spark. I use Intellij Idea. I did an executable-jar from it but when I try to launch it via windows console there is an error about lack of some class. I can't figure out there is a problem because I've added it in  block in my .pom file. Also when I look inside .jar I see that library with that class:

*needed library in .jar:*
[image: needed library in .jar]

I tried to use both plugins: maven-shade-plugin and maven-assembly-plugin and result is the same. And I tried to set this library explicitly in classpath through project structure->libraries in Intellij:

*classpath in IDEA:*
[image: classpath in idea].

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.{ALS, ALSModel}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}
import scala.collection.{Map, Set}
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.util.Random
object RunRecommender {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark: SparkSession =SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("Recommender Engines with Audioscrobbler data")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "spark-warehouse")
      .getOrCreate()

    val rawUserArtistData: Dataset[String] = spark.read.textFile("user_artist_data.txt")
    val rawArtistData: Dataset[String] = spark.read.textFile("artist_data.txt")
    val rawArtistAlias: Dataset[String] = spark.read.textFile("artist_alias.txt")

    val runRecommender: RunRecommender = new RunRecommender(spark)
    runRecommender.preparation(rawUserArtistData, rawArtistData, rawArtistAlias)
    runRecommender.model(rawUserArtistData, rawArtistData, rawArtistAlias)
    runRecommender.evaluate(rawUserArtistData, rawArtistAlias)
    runRecommender.recommend(rawUserArtistData, rawArtistData, rawArtistAlias)
  }

}
```

and here is my .pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>recommends</groupId>
    <artifactId>recommends</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Recommender Engine with Audioscrobbler data</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mavencentral</id>
        <name>Maven Central</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>RunRecommender</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>RunRecommender</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and here is stack-trace when I try to run jar:

```
16/11/06 11:56:40 WARN SparkContext: Use an existing SparkContext, some configuration may not take effect.
16/11/06 11:56:40 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'spark-warehouse'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: text. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.text(DataFrameReader.scala:492)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.textFile(DataFrameReader.scala:528)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.textFile(DataFrameReader.scala:501)
        at RunRecommender$.main(RunRecommender.scala:20)
        at RunRecommender.main(RunRecommender.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: text.DefaultSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DataSource.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DataSource.scala:130)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5.apply(DataSource.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5.apply(DataSource.scala:130)
        at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:130)
        ... 9 more
16/11/06 11:56:40 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
1
```

Comment: It's looking for a class whose *fully-qualified name* is `text.DefaultSource`. The directory you showed as screenshot of was for the package `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text`.

Comment: thank you for comment! where should I add it?

Comment: Add what? I'm not sure what you're asking - nor do I know the solution, I just thought it would help you diagnose it.

Comment: This was very helpful for me.  I ran into an issue where I was getting this log line `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .DefaultSource`.  This led me to notice that there was a bug in our code setting the string name for output type to `""`.

Answer (score 0):

I had look-alike problem, for me this element in maven was missing:

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be easily sorted out only if you try to run the same jar using by spark-submit to run jar instead of java -jar in terminal.

Comment: Is this a comment, or an answer? If it is an answer can you expand on what the output of spark-submit would add and how that would be used to solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is that `Spark` uses `Service Locator` pattern.
In `spark-sql_2.10` `META-INF/services` there is file `org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister` which registers datasources:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSinkProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.RateStreamProvider
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.TextSocketSourceProvider
```

The same file is in `spark-mllib_2.11` `META-INF/services`.
Maven `assembly` plugin takes one file (the first in dependencies, with the same name) from the jars without merging it. So required classes are included in the uber jar. But service locator configuration file `org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister` is not merged from two files. Thus only datasources from `spark-mllib_2.11` are registered:

```
org.apache.spark.ml.source.libsvm.LibSVMFileFormat
```

To fix the issue use shade plugin and add transformer to merge service locator configuration:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        ...
                        </transformers> 
                        ...
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```